# DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql : no such table: League

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to connect to the sqllite3 database using python. The error is:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM League': 
no such table: League
```

Python code:

```
import sqlite3
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(pat))
#database = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "database.sqlite")

#with sqlite3.connect(database) as conn:
#    
#    print("Connection Successful",conn)
#    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Country", conn)

pat = r'C:\Users\pouru\Downloads\soccer'
database = pat + 'database.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
print("Connection Successful",conn)
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM League', conn)
```

It says connection successful but when I insert the last statement to get the table data, it produces the above error. I tried to solve it using the absolute path way like the code I have commented above but it gives the same error.

Can anyone give me an idea to solve this? I have tried with all the tables. It works well on the SQL interface but not in python.

Comment: Try replacing `read_sql_query` function with `read_sql`. Let's see what happens.

Comment: I tried that too..but I got the same error ..EVerything works fine conn object is created and it displays connections successful ..but as soon as I try to get data from table it does not work ....and I chcecked the tables variable ..it is a (0,5) size dataframe and it is all empty for more information ....Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: @MayankPorwal do you have any other ideas which might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the pat = r'C:\Users\pouru\Downloads\soccer' to

```
pat = 'C:\Users\pouru\Downloads\soccer\'
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it didn't work with this as well and finally, I did this

pat = 'C:\\Users\\pouru\\Downloads\\soccer\\' 
and it works here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I shortened the code and tested it on Windows 11 and got the same error. I then printed the path and found that it was incorrect. Resolving the path worked for me so I suggest making sure the path to the `.db` file is correct.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\sqlite\Kannat\northwind.db')
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName from categories', conn)
print(df)
conn.close()
```

The error message is misleading as it refers to the table not being found when it was in fact the `.db` file that was not found.