# how to fix : "Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM Country': no such table: Country"

Tags: python, pandas

I have written this code  and tried all the possible solutions available everywhere. still stuck up at this.

```
pat = 'C:\\Users\\gpsin\\Desktop\\football project\\'

database = pat + 'database1.sqlite'

con = sqlite3.connect(database)

print("Connection Successful",con)

countries = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Country', con)

matches = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from Match", con)

leagues = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from League", con)

teams = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from Team", con)

tempmatch = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from Match", con)

matches3 = matches2 = matches
```

it shows error :

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM Country': no such table:
>   Country

though database is created 
Connection Successful

Comment: If the connection is successful and you get this error, then the table Country does not exist on your database, or at least not in the context you're trying to call it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have table **Country** in your database. You need to have a check.

Otherwise, your path may have mistakes. See this post:[DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql : no such table: League](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357551/databaseerror-execution-failed-on-sql-no-such-table-league)